# SQL Server ODBC Connect to Database Fails With "SSL Security Error"

Tags: ssl, sql-server-2012, odbc

I have been digging for answers for this issue and have not been able to solve it. I believe it is a TLS issue but nothing I've tried fixes it. Setup ...
The reporting application server trying to connect to the database server via ODBC SQL Server is using the SQLSRV32.DLL version 6. (I know the driver is old and updating would probably fix the issue but that is not so easy to do). I have confirmed on both hosts that TLS 1.0 is not enabled. I did this by checking the registry under "SCHANNEL->Protocols" and using "Internet Options -> Advanced Tab". Both only have TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 checked. The error is "Error 772; Connection Failed; SSL Security Error". I found a host with an updated ODBC driver (v10) and it can connect to the database.

I have another DB and reporting server with what appears to be identical configurations, using the same old SQL driver, but they are not having the issue. Trying to connect from this reporting server to the other database fails too.

I believe this is an issue with the database server, possibly SQL Server, but am stuck on what to look for.

Any guidance on what else to look at would be appreciated.

Comment: Has SQL Server been updated to the latest patch (with TLS 1.2 enabled)? Does the reporting application trust the SQL Server certificate (must trust the CA issuing the certificate)? Is there any reason you *don't* want to update the ODBC driver?

Comment: SQL server is up-to-date. I am looking into geting an updated driver but that will take time. TLS 1.2 is enabled (I think). It shows as enabled in "Internet Options" (both 1.1 and 1.2 are checked) and in the registry on both servers.I made changes to the DB registry for Protocols and restarted but that did not fix it. I still think I am having a TLS issue. No machines using SQLSRV32.DLL can connect to the database but this configuration works for another set of servers.

Comment: Which version of windows is running on the client (reporting app) and server (SQL Server machine)? If Windows 7 or Windows Server 2012 or earlier, you need to install a special patch for TLS 1.2, and enable the correct settings in the registry